# Want to call function in child component from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have one component with name Company and from that component I am opening one popup modal, below is code for that.

Now in that popup modal user is uploading file and submit it, and then I am calling API.

Once API return success response then I want to call one function from Company component in that popup modal component.

html code

```
<div class="fileUploadButton">
   <button color="primary" (click)="openUploadDocumentDialog()">
      Add Other Documents
   </button>
</div>
```

ts file code

```
public openUploadDocumentDialog() : void {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UploadDocumentDialogComponent, {
     width: '50vw',
     panelClass: ['documentsUploadDialog', 'ceqUserDialog'],
     data: {
        companyid: this.route.snapshot.params['company_guid']
      }
    });
  }
```

Now in this upload document dialog component user is uploading file, so once user upload file then click on Save then I am calling API.

It is successfully calling it. What I want is once this API get called successfully and returned response then I want to call method from Company component.

Upload-document-dialog.ts file

```
public uploadFileHandler(): void {
     this.apiService.uploadDocumentFile(this.uploadedFile)
       .subscribe({
         next: (event) => {
           if (event.data) {
           **// here I want to call function from Parent company dialog.**
             this.dialogRef.close(event.data);
           }
         },
         error: (err) => {
           this.snackBar.open('Connect error! Please try again!', 'Ok', {
             duration: 2000,
           });
         },
       });
  }
```

Comment: The method you want to call on close is in the parent-component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would go about solving the problem. I think in general it is 'bad practice' to call a function from the parent from the dialog box. So to get around this we would do the following.

Subscribe to `dialogRef.afterClosed()` call.

For example you could do something like this on the Company component

`.html`

```
<div class="fileUploadButton">
   <button color="primary" (click)="openUploadDocumentDialog()">
      Add Other Documents
   </button>
</div>
```

`.ts`

```
public openUploadDocumentDialog() : void {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UploadDocumentDialogComponent, {
     width: '50vw',
     panelClass: ['documentsUploadDialog', 'ceqUserDialog'],
     data: {
        companyid: this.route.snapshot.params['company_guid']
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(response=> {
       // 'response' will be 'event.data' from this.dialogRef.close(event.data)
     })
  }
```